# Avoiding double encoding in <INPUT> while using htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, xss, htmlspecialchars

Say you have a text `<INPUT>` for a user's name and they decide to type in

```
Johnny's Pizza
```

This is saved in DB as

```
Johnny's Pizza
```

But if the user decides to edit, I repopulate the text `<INPUT>` as follows

```
echo form_input('name', htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

which will show as

```
Johnny&#039;s Pizza
```

inside the input field.

PHP.net has a [comment here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#99185) suggesting to use

```
echo form_input('name', htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', FALSE));
```

that is, `FALSE` referring to `$double_encoding`, but I still get

```
Johnny&#039;s Pizza
```

in the input field.

Is there a way around this double encoding? Is this something that can be fixed while still using `ENT_QUOTES`?

Using Codeigniter  2.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `htmlspecialchars` is the correct approach, and won't give the result you describe if you output it directly into the page.

Presumably the `form_input` function expects to receive text and not HTML, so it runs `htmlspecialchars` itself. If so, the solution is to just pass it text and not encode the value for HTML first.

Comment: I'm using codeigniter as framework here - so if you're correct, you're saying I could drop `htmlspecialchars` from the form inputs?

Comment: apparently, codeigniter's form helper already takes care of `htmlspecialchars` running on your values --- http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/158843/P15 --- so the way I'm doing it here, means I'm doing it twice

Comment: If we find [that function](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L185), and follow through until we hit [this function](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Common.php#L561) we can see that `htmlspecialchars` is already being used and you don't need to use it again.

Comment: right on --- nice little feature of codeigniter I must say --- thx

Comment: I'd consider it a fundamental requirement for any library that generated form markup.